# Is this question about limiting factors answerable?

Tags: homework, ecology, photosynthesis

This is from a Singapore-Cambridge GCE O-level Biology exam (a national exam for 16-year-olds). The exam board maintains that the question is "correct and accurate"—but isn't there a typo in option C?

[image]

Here's my argument:

- Merely increasing the light intensity at either Points 1 or 2 speeds up photosynthesis, but varying the light intensity at Points 3 and 4 doesn't.

  Therefore, **light intensity is limiting photosynthesis at only Points 1 & 2**.
- At Point 3, merely doubling the $\ce{CO2}$ concentration speeds up photosynthesis; on the other hand, the graph shows no evidence that varying the $\ce{CO2}$ concentrations at Points 1, 2 or 4 speeds up photosynthesis.

  Therefore, **$\ce{CO2}$ concentration is limiting photosynthesis conclusively at only Point 3**.

As this is a data-inference question, all the four answer choices are invalid *deductions*.

(Asserting that $\ce{CO2}$ concentration is a limiting factor at Point 4 requires *assuming* that raising $\ce{CO2}$ concentration beyond 0.08% continues speeding up photosynthesis.)

Excluding Point 4 from Option C will render this question finally answerable.

Comment: With your logic wouldn't that also mean that point 3 requires assuming that decreasing the carbon dioxide concentration would decrease photosynthesis rate? In statistics when you want to test if one parameter affects another it's sufficient to test a high and a low point.

Comment: @Cell No--because it stands to reason that $\ce{CO2}$ concentration is limiting photosynthesis in a given setup if varying it (in either direction) speeds up photosynthesis.

Comment: You misunderstand. It could be the case that a third curve exists at 0.02% carbon dioxide that begins to plateau at point 1. Also "rate limiting" could mean slow down too.

Comment: @Cell $\ce{CO2}$ concentration is said to be limiting photosynthesis in a given setup as long as increasing (or decreasing, for that matter) it there speeds up photosynthesis.  In other words, the fact that increasing $\ce{CO2}$ at point 3 increases photosynthesis is sufficient to assert that $\ce{CO2}$ is a limiting factor there -- regardless of whether decreasing $\ce{CO2}$ there increases or decreases photosynthesis.

Comment: So, why do you think that logic doesn't apply at point 4?

Comment: @tyersome The graph displays no faster photosynthesis than at point 4.

Answer (score 2):

I think your thinking is fine, but you're being a bit pedantic about it. I don't think there is any typo.

The purpose of the question is for you to understand that there are two limiting factors here: light and CO<sub>2</sub>.

You can identify points in the graph where light is limiting because there is a slope with increasing light, and you can identify points in the graph where CO<sub>2</sub> is limiting because light no longer increases the rate, and that the plateau level changes with different CO<sub>2</sub> levels.

Yes, you are right, there could be other yet-unrevealed-to-you limiting factors here, but there is nothing in the graph to show this. You would need to see another set of lines where increasing CO<sub>2</sub> further does not change the plateau level, and/or where the shape changes.

Chalk it up to [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor). Without further information besides what is on this graph, if I asked you to draw your *prediction* about what the line would look like at 0.12% CO<sub>2</sub>, you should draw another line that follows the other and then plateaus at a third, higher level.

Comment: 1. Without knowing that the optimal $CO_2$ concentration is above $0.08\%,$ one might guess that at point $4,$ $CO_2$ is a limiting factor, but one can't be certain. 2. At room temperature, the optimal $CO_2$ concentration for photosynthesis is actually $0.10\%.$ So, a $0.12\%\: CO_2$ graph would be no higher than—in fact, the same graph as—a $0.10\% \:CO_2$ graph.

Comment: @ryang There is no data in the graph supporting any limiting factors besides CO2 and light.